# How to compare variables and find difference in python

Tags: python

I have two variables readARP and readFPING which will have a series of IP's listed in them and I want to compare one to the other. After comparing them I would like to print out the difference if there is any.

```
readARP = scanProcess.read()
readFPING = fpingscanPocess.read()

>>> print readARP
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.1

>>> print readFPING
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1
192.168.1.12
```

I want to compare both and then print 192.168.2.1 192.168.1.12 192.168.1.100 since they are unique to the two.

P.S. What is "readFPING" referred to as in python I have adapted the term variable

After I find out what is different how could I add the different to a variable. 
Example: 192.168.1.2 isnt in readFPING but I then want to add it (Creating a master ip list)

Comment: That's called a variable, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as it can get. You can use the set [symmetric_difference](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) to find the unique elements in both the input source.

```
readARP=scanProcess.read()
readFPING = fpingscanPocess.read()
print readARP
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.1

print readFPING
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1
192.168.1.12

print '\n'.join(set(readARP.splitlines()).symmetric_difference(readFPING.splitlines()))
192.168.1.100
192.168.2.1
192.168.1.12
```

Comment: Ya this works thanks a lot. How hard is it to put the result of " print '\n'.join(set(readARP.splitlines()).symmetric_difference(readFPING.splitlines()))" into a variable following the same format as readARP and readFPING?

Comment: @S-Ns-3, It would be as simple as replacing the print with the variable name.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that before but I tried putting it in quotes which messed me up :P

Answer (score 2):

```
for IP in readARP:
    if IP not in readFPING:
        print IP

for IP in readFPING:
    if IP not in readARP:
        print IP
```

There are obviously easier ways to do this, but since you're new to Python I'll keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks this was right but the other answer was what I was really looking for, I edited my initial question afterwords thanks for the quick response though. I gave you rep for it and for the variable python knowledge.

Comment: On a lighter note, something which is easier isn't it simple too :-)